# Troubleshooting 'Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript' warning in RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

A warning message

```
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
```

appears when a simple R Markdown document is knitted to PDF:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

![foo](bar.png)
```

The `bar.png` image is embedded into PDF all right, but it looks like there is a spelling error in called `ghostcript` command (shouldn't it be ghost**s**cript after the name of [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com) interpreter?). How to properly address this warning message?

My `xfun::session_info()` output:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042), RStudio 1.4.1103

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 compiler_4.0.4  digest_0.6.27   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.2      graphics_4.0.4  grDevices_4.0.4
  highr_0.8       htmltools_0.5.0 jsonlite_1.7.1  knitr_1.31      magrittr_2.0.1  markdown_1.1    methods_4.0.4  
  mime_0.9        rlang_0.4.10    rmarkdown_2.7   stats_4.0.4     stringi_1.5.3   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.27   
  tools_4.0.4     utils_4.0.4     xfun_0.19       yaml_2.2.1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell R where to find ghostscript. For Windows, download ghostscript from http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html
After installing ghostscript, we still need to tell R where to find ghostscript. To do so, it is necessary to set adapt your system’s Path variable:
Go to Control Panel → System and Security → System → Advanced System Settings → computer name, domain and workgroup settings → Advanced → Environment Variables
Find the Path variable within System Variables, select it and click on edit.
Add C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin (or the directory where you installed ghostscript to) to the Path variable. In Windows 10, you can do this by clicking on New and entering the path. In other Windows versions, just append the path to the variable value, seperated by a semicolon.
Restart R
For MacOS, download and install the Ghostscript 9.23 package from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/
Restart R

I found the solution from this website https://rnbeads.org/data/installing_rnbeads.html

Comment: Adding `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin` to the user PATH indeed eliminated the error message. I installed Ghostscript with Chocolatey and I thought the shim creation and PATH addition are done automatically which is apparently not the case. Still interesting to see what appears to be a typo in 'ghostcript' (missing 's') in the error message itself.

Comment: perfect and well-articulated solution - many thanks !

Comment: Hi, any ideas how to solve this in linux/ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I followed your directions exactly Hana and it's not working... even after a restart of R and my computer. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I followed Hana's suggested solution to the letter (including a restart) and my R session still could not find ghostscript. I had to include this line of code in my script for it to work:

`Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.54.0/bin/gswin64c.exe")`